# Constructor overloading, how do i proceed?

Tags: java, constructor-overloading

In my assignment we are practicing constructor overloading (on paper). I have to implement these 3 constructors (fill out) and the main constructor has to generate a circle with the coordinates (0,0) and a radius of 1. I already tried to implement the first two constructors, but don't know what to do in the third constructor. As always thank you guys for your help.

```
public class Center
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
}

public class Circle
{
    private Center c;
    private double radius;

    public Circle()
    {
        this(0, 0, 1); //TO-DO
    }

    public Circle(Center c, double radius)
    {
        this(0, 0, radius); //TO-DO
    }

    public Circle(double x, double y, double radius)
    {
        //TO-DO
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second constructor is not correct either, you are not even using the `Center c` passed to it.

Comment: The last constructor is where one must assign class members using the given parameters.

Comment: Hint: a `Center` is nothing else than an `x`- and an `y`-coordinate.

Comment: Your problem is not in how to overload a constructor. Your problem is in how to initialize a "Center"

Comment: Please refer your text box, or use some online resource like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I will try to figure it out with your hints for 10min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the values to the respective variables here:

```
public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
    this.c = new Center();
    this.c.x = x;
    this.c.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

And your second constructor should be like:

```
public Circle(Center c, double radius){
    this(c.x,c.y,radius); 
}
```

Comment: This won't work because `Center` is never initialized.

Comment: 3rd constructor: Since the method is not static, i have to create a new Center object and then i have access to the x and y in the "Center" class right? 

And in the second constructor we don't need to create a new Center object, because we are not accessing the class Center. We are using c because it is from the "Center" class?

Thank you, very helpful.

Comment: Constructor not method. And yes, you have to create an object to access the properties of Center.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
public Circle() {
    this(0,0,1); 
}

public Circle(Center c, double radius){
    this(c.x, c.y,radius); //you need to use the center's coordinates
}

public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
    this.c = new Center(x, y);
    this.radius = radius;
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is homework and he cannot modify the `Center` class to contain a constructor of `(x, y)`, he most likely needs to use the `no-args` constructor, `new Center()` and manually set the values after since they are `public`.  Though your solution would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Due to your class is defined:

```
public class Circle {
    private Center c;
    private double radius;
    ...
}
```

The key points here are the variable `c` which is of a class `Center` and the variable `radius` which is of a primitive type `double`, you need to define both.

As you can see, the third constructor provides you with three variables: `x`, `y` and `radius`. The only way these three can be matched to the `c` and `radius` is:

```
public Circle(double x, double y, double radius) {
    c = new Center(x, y);
    this.radius = radius; //here you must use `this` reference to avoid
    //collision between the radius variable from the class and its 
    //counerpart from the constructor.
}
```

In this constructor, we create a new `Center` to satisfy the `c` variable, we put there `x` and `y`, as it needed in the declaration of the `Center` constructor. Also we assign the `radius` variable.